# Dropdowns on Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am new to Django and am using it simply to allow users to easily edit database tables through the admin site. I have two tables with some fields in common. I want the common fields to appear as dropdowns in one of the tables. I can't figure out how to make multiple dropdowns. Is this even the best GUI tool to use for simple databases?

Here is my code so far:

```
class places(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
 description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 def __unicode__(self):
      return self.name # CAN I ADD A CONDITIONAL HERE THAT WILL RETURN 'DESCRIPTION'?

 class more_places(models.Model):
      name = models.ForeignKey('places', null=True, blank=True, db_column = 'Feature_Name', related_name='featureName') # THIS IS DROPDOWN #1
      description = models.ForeignKey('places', null=True, blank=True, db_column = 'Version', related_name='version') # I WANT THIS TO BE DROPDOWN #2
      more_data = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Comment: I don't think you understand how Django's models work.  You can't set `more_places.description` as a foreign key on `places` *and* set the `db_column` explicitly.

Comment: Indeed, I am unfamiliar with the models. Do you have any suggestions for creating two dropdowns pulling different data from the same table?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any errors in your model. And it is working as **two** dropdowns in Django v1.3. But I also don't understand the need of specifying **related_name**

Comment: Two drop-downs are indeed being created, but they both contain the same information ('name' data from the 'places' table). I'd like the second drop-down to display 'description' data. I read that related_name specifications are needed when using multiple foreign key references to a single table.

Comment: Dropdown lists are populated using `__unicode__` method of related object

Comment: Right. So how can I populate the second drop-down with data from the 'places' 'description' field?

Comment: In this case I would switch to generic classes (CreateView and UpdateView). It is rather easy to write your own template, leaving all logic to generics.